# Exporting a variable with a backslash

Tags: bash

I am working on an install script, of the following form:

```
# get username
echo "Please enter your oracle username:"
read -p "> " username
stty -echo

# get password
echo "Please enter your oracle password:"
read -r -p "> " password; echo
stty echo

# -- Create all text to output to config
finaluser=$usernamelabel$username
finalpassword=$passwordlabel$password
echo -e $finaluser"\n"$finalpassword > $configfile
```

The problem is, if a password of the form like 'z\2z', it is outputted to $configfile as:

```
z^Bz
```

Is there any easy way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't embed the `\n`, and then you don't need the `-e` option which is also interpreting the `\2`.

```
echo "$finaluser" >$configfile
echo "$finalpassword" >>$configfile
```

or

```
cat >$configfile <<EOF
$finaluser
$finalpassword
EOF
```

or a third way if you really want to use a single command

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' "$finaluser" "$finalpassword"
```

Comment: +1 for the `printf` version. Yet more ways: `echo  "$finaluser"$'\n'"$finalpassword" > $configfile` or `{ echo  "$finaluser"; echo "$finalpassword"; } > $configfile`